# How to change Laravel Jetstream default routes to custome?

Tags: php, authentication, routes, laravel-jetstream, laravel-10

I'm a newcomer to Laravel, working with Laravel Version 10.2 and Jetstream Version 3.2 for my project. I'm aiming to modify the default route of Jetstream to a custom route. Kindly take a look at the provided example:

Jetstream default route : http://127.0.0.1:8000/login | http://127.0.0.1:8000/register

I want Like this,

Custom route : http://127.0.0.1:8000/custom_login | http://127.0.0.1:8000/custom_register

I'm having trouble locating the Jetstream route. Despite attempting various approaches, such as creating a custom service provider, still no luck.

custom service provider:

```
public function register(): void
    {
        Fortify::routeName('custom-login', 'login');         
        Fortify::routeName('custom-register', 'register');    
    }
```

Please advice.